# Load a java agent during runtime on OpenJDK?

Tags: java, attach-api

I've found many answers pointing me to `VirtualMachine#loadAgent`, which would honestly be great, except I don't have a VirtualMachine class, anywhere. I've been quite confused about it as well, however I do not seem to have any of the Attach API. I am using OpenJDK 8:

```sh
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b05, mixed mode)
```

What other methods are there to load a java agent? The environment I am working in would have very little success at passing `-javaagent:` arguments, as it's meant to be injected into the classpath at runtime, and obviously any average user isn't going to want to/have the knowledge to manually change the JVM args just for my specific program.

On another note, just to make sure that this class is meant to be a part of OpenJDK, as isn't something designed only for the java hotspot VM, I downloaded OpenJDK code from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/, and found the VirtualMachine.java file, which means that it definitely is meant to exist

Comment: The attach API including the VirtualMachine class is in **tools.jar** which is not in the default classpath. Add tools.jar to your classpath.

Comment: Thank you! It would've saved me hours of hair tearing if someone had just mentioned this in the original posts I had found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've found many answers pointing me to `VirtualMachine::loadAgent`, which would honestly be great, except I don't have a `VirtualMachine` class, anywhere.

Lets start this the javadocs for [`VirtualMachine`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java9/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html) and [`VirtualMachineDescriptor`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java9/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachineDescriptor.html)

Clearly, the `VirtualMachine` class is defined by the Java class libraries, so the class exists.  So the question is why you can't find the class itself at compile time and/or at runtime.

For older JVMs prior to Java 6, the `VirtualMachine` class was semi-internal and you needed to access it from the `tools.jar` file:

- [How to import and use com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099352/how-to-import-and-use-com-sun-jdi-virtualmachine)
- [Accessing VirtualMachine and HotspotVirtualMachine classes from JDK1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458683/accessing-virtualmachine-and-hotspotvirtualmachine-classes-from-jdk1-5)

When the `VirtualMachine` class became an official API in Java 6, its name changed to `com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine`.  However, it was still in the `tools.jar` file rather than the main `rt.jar` file. This continued until (and including) Java 8.

In Java 9, the modules system was introduced and things changed. Neither `rt.jar` or `tools.jar` exist anymore.  To access these classes now (Java 9 onwards) you need to include `requires jdk.attach` in your `module.info` file.